# Openssl sha1 different to what I find online

Tags: bash

My problem is this:

For example:

```
echo "123456" | openssl sha1
```

outputs

```
c4f9375f9834b4e7f0a528cc65c055702bf5f24a
```

but if I hash "123456" with an online tool (for example http://www.sha1hash.com) I get

```
7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b
```

Which is different to what openssl sha1 got me..
What am I doing wrong? Am I using openssl sha1 wrong? Or am I missing something like salt or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
echo -n 123456 | shasum
```

or

```
echo -n 123456 | openssl sha1
```

> -n     do not output the trailing newline